# Shading in a rotation without a canvas transformation

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, shading

I'm currently working on a magnifying glass as an object without making use of the spy library. It is written as a \newcommand since I have to use it to some extense. My problem is the shading for the handle. I work with \shade but as soon as I turn to angles different than 90, 180 or 270, the shading looks strange. A canvas transformation had the desired effect, but since I use this command inside scope with scaling and shifting, a canvas transformation placed the magnifying glass at the wrong coordinates. Is there a way how can I achieve the shading of the handle like for the first magnifying glass for a different angle and get the correct coordinates when I call this command inside a scaled or shifted scope?

I hope the question is clear and I apologize in advance for the rather strange construction of the coordinates, I did not clean up the code yet. A minimal example looks like this

Thank you very much

Minimal example with some explanation:

The first argument is the x-coordinate of the center of the magnifying glass, the second argument the y-coordinate. The third one is the radius and the fourth gives the angle of the handle.

```
  \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}                               %Tikz ist kein Zeichenprogramm
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}                    %3D Plots

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections, decorations,circuits.ee.IEC, calc, decorations.markings,pgfplots.groupplots,3d,shadows,spy,fadings,fit}

\usepackage{pgfplots}                       %Für Plots
%\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\pgfplotsset{%
cycle list={blue\\red\\green\\orange\\},
every axis plot post/.append style={mark=none, smooth},
compat=1.11
}

\newcommand{\lupe}[4]{\Slupe{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{5}{#3*.15}{.5}{.05}}
\newcommand{\Slupe}[8]{
\begin{scope}[rotate around={#4:(#1,#2)}]
%\begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate around={#4:(#1,#2)}}]
\draw [name path=Glassrand] (#1,#2) circle (#3);
\shade[ball color=blue,opacity=#8] (#1,#2) circle (0.95*#3);
\draw[fill=gray,even odd rule] (#1,#2) circle (#3) circle (0.95*#3) ;
\draw (#1,#2) circle (0.95*#3);


\path[draw=none,name path=linkerstiel] (#1,#2)--++  (0:#3+#3)--++(0+90:#6)--(#1,#2);
\path[draw=none,name path=rechterstiel] (#1,#2)--++  (0:#3+#3)--++(0-90:#6)--(#1,#2);
\path[draw=none,name path=linkerstielcenter] (#1,#2)--++(90:#6) coordinate (StielBreite1);
\path[draw=none,name path=rechterstielcebter] (#1,#2)--++(-90:#6) coordinate (StielBreite2);

\path[draw=none]  (#1,#2) --++ (0:3*#3) --++(90:#6) coordinate (StielEnde1);
\path[draw=none]  (#1,#2) --++ (0:3*#3)--++(-90:#6) coordinate (StielEnde2);

\path[draw=none,name path=StielAusrichtungEins] (StielEnde1) -- (StielBreite1);
\path[draw=none,name path=StielAusrichtungZwei] (StielEnde2) -- (StielBreite2);

\path [name intersections={of=Glassrand and StielAusrichtungEins}];
\coordinate (StielAnfang1) at (intersection-1);

\path [name intersections={of=Glassrand and StielAusrichtungZwei}];
\coordinate (StielAnfang2) at (intersection-1);

\coordinate (griff1) at ($(StielAnfang1) !1! (StielEnde1)$);
\coordinate (griff2) at ($(StielAnfang2) !1! (StielEnde2)$);

\coordinate (griff3) at ($(StielAnfang1) !.15! (StielEnde1)$);
\coordinate (griff4) at ($(StielAnfang2) !.15! (StielEnde2)$);

\path  (griff3)--++(0,.1*#3) coordinate (griff5);
\path  (griff4)--++(0,-.1*#3) coordinate (griff6);
\path  (StielEnde1)--++(0,.1*#3) coordinate (griff7);
\path  (StielEnde2)--++(0,-.1*#3) coordinate (griff8);

\coordinate (fixpunkt1) at ($(griff7)!.3!(griff8)$);
\coordinate (fixpunkt2) at ($(griff5)!.3!(griff6)$);
\coordinate (fixpunkt3) at ($(StielAnfang1)!.3!(StielAnfang2)$);
\coordinate (fixpunkt4) at ($(griff1)!.3!(griff2)$);

\path [draw=none] (griff1) --++(0,.1*#3) coordinate (test1);
\path [draw=none] (griff1) --++(.1*#3,0) coordinate (test2);

\path [draw=none] (griff2) --++(0,-.1*#3) coordinate (test3);
\path [draw=none] (griff2) --++(.1*#3,0) coordinate (test4);

\shade[top color=black, bottom color=white,shading angle=#4] (StielAnfang1) -- (fixpunkt3)--(fixpunkt4) -- (griff1);
\shade[top color=white, bottom color=black,shading angle=#4] (StielAnfang2) -- (fixpunkt3)--(fixpunkt4) -- (griff2);
\%end{scope}
\end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\lupe{0}{0}{1}{0}
\lupe{0}{-2}{1}{-45}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

1. I tried to have the lighting on the handle coherent with the handle's position.  You can modify the result by modifying the function `forHColor`.
2. I simplified the handle's construction; it is based on the introduction of the points `\H{+}` and `\H{-}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math}

\begin{document}

\tikzmath{
  function forHColor(\i, \b) {
    if \b<91 then {
      return 50*(cos((1-\i)^2*360)+1);
    } else {
      return 50*(cos(\i^2*360)+1);
    };
  };
}

\tikzset{
  pics/magnifying/.code args={xcenter #1, ycenter #2, radius #3, hangle #4}{
    \tikzmath{
      coordinate \H{+}, H{-};
      real \width, \da, \qw;
      \da = 8;  % controls handle's width
      \H{+} = (#1, #2) + (#4+\da : #3);
      \H{-} = (#1, #2) + (#4-\da : #3);
      \width = veclen(\Hx{+}-\Hx{-}, \Hy{+}-\Hy{-});  % handle's width
      \qw = .05;  % controls the number of steps for handle's color
      {%
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \cm using {forHColor(\i, #4)}]
        in {0, \qw, ..., 1}{%
          \draw[gray!70!black!\cm, line width={\width/10}]
          ($(\H{+})!\i!(\H{-})$) -- ++(#4 : 2.1*#3);  % handle's length
        }
      };
      { \shade[ball color=blue, opacity=.07] (#1, #2) circle (.95*#3);
        \draw[very thin, fill=gray, even odd rule]
        (#1, #2) circle (#3) circle (.95*#3);
      };
    }
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw pic {magnifying={xcenter -1, ycenter -2, radius 1.4, hangle 30}};
  \draw pic {magnifying={xcenter 5, ycenter 0, radius 1.7, hangle 130}};  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```